transform method on nuxt apollo plugin useAsyncQuery not working
I'm using the nuxt-modules/apollo plugin to query my CMS. The data returns as expected, but I'm trying to run a transform method to lowerCase some of the properties.
I can run a method after the fact, but I'm trying to use Nuxt's useAsyncData transform option to keep it part of the query. I believe this will help with performance.
My attempt looks something like this:
const { data, error } = await useAsyncQuery(query, {
  id: "someIdForTheQuery",
  transform: (data2) => {
    return {
      ...data2,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    };
  },
});

I'm able to get it to work without the plugin at all (using useAsyncData and $fetch).  I'm not sure if something in my syntax is wrong, or maybe the plugin still being in alpha doesn't support it yet.
I tried returning different objects, properties, debugger and console logs. It looks like it isn't hit at all.
Any direction or advice is welcome.
Thanks

We figure it out, we needed to separate the fields into separate objects:
const { data, error } = await useAsyncQuery(
{
  query,
  variables: {  id: "someIdForTheQuery" }
},
{ 
 transform: (data2) => {
    return {
      ...data2,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    };
});

Details found in the composables file in the node module
/**
 * `useAsyncQuery` resolves the GraphQL query asynchronously in a SSR-friendly composable.
 *
 * @param opts An object containing the query, variables, clientId, context, and cache options.
 * @param options Customize the underlying `useAsyncData` composable.
 */

OR
/**
 * `useAsyncQuery` resolves the GraphQL query asynchronously in a SSR-friendly composable.
 *
 * @param query A GraphQL query string parsed into an AST with the gql template literal.
 * @param variables An object containing all of the GraphQL variables your query requires to execute.
 * @param clientId The name of the Apollo Client to use. Defaults to `default`.
 * @param context The context object that's passed along your link chain.
 * @param options Customize the underlying `useAsyncData` composable.
 */

